# How to make selected value in form stay selected?

Tags: php, mysql

In my database I got a table (`band`) with 2 columns (`band_id` and `title`). In PHP I got variable that stores selected id (`selected_band_id`) and a form that reads values from the table and displays form.

Table:

```
+---------+---------+
| band_id | title   |
+---------+---------+
|       1 | Title 1 |
|       2 | Title 2 |
|       3 | Title 3 |
+---------+---------+
```

PHP:

```
<?php
  $query = "SELECT `band`.`band_id`, `band`.`title` FROM `band`";
  $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);
  if (!$result) {
    die("Database query failed.");
  }
?>

<?php
  if (isset($_POST['select_band'])) {
    $selected_band_id = $_POST['select_band'];
  }
?>

<form method="post" name="form_band" action="">
  <select name="select_band" onchange="javascript: submit()">
    <?php
      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "<option value=".$row["band_id"] . ">" .$row["title"] ."</option>";
      }
    ?>
 </select>
</form>
```

How to make selected variable stay selected (shown) in a form? It always jumps to the first item in a list. I can't figure this out with PHP. Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Where is `$result` and the rest of related code?

Comment: Added. `mysqli` variable contains `mysqli_connect` parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should fix your PHP code:

```html
<?php
  $query = "SELECT `band`.`band_id`, `band`.`title` FROM `band`";
  $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);
  if (!$result) {
    die("Database query failed.");
  }
?>

<?php
  if (isset($_POST['select_band'])) {
    $selected_band_id = $_POST['select_band'];
  }
?>

<form method="post" name="form_band" action="">
  <select name="select_band" onchange="javascript: submit()">
    <?php
      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $selected = '';
        if($selected_band_id == $row["band_id"]){
              $selected = ' selected';
        }
        echo "<option value=".$row["band_id"] . $selected . ">" .$row["title"] ."</option>";
      }
    ?>
 </select>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Will look into `selected`.

Answer (score 1):

`<option value...` has a tag `selected`. This one you should set for the correct band. So if $row["band_id"] == $selected_band_id, set `selected` in this `<option>`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  $query = "SELECT `band`.`band_id`, `band`.`title` FROM `band`";
  $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);
  if (!$result) {
    die("Database query failed.");
  }
?>

<?php
  if (isset($_POST['select_band'])) {
    $selected_band_id = $_POST['select_band'];
  }
?>

<form method="post" name="form_band" action="">
  <select name="select_band" onchange="javascript: submit()">
    <?php
      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
     {?>
        <option value="$row['band_id']" <?if($row['band_id']==$selected_band_id){echo "selected";}?>>$row["title"]</option>
     // Here, selected item will get as selected
      <?}
    ?>
 </select>
</form>
```